# Map from scalar field to topological vector space is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

If $X$ is a topological vector space and $R$ is a scalar field and $f:R \rightarrow X$ given by $f(\alpha)=\alpha x$. Then the map $f$ is continuous. How can we show that?

It is a step used in Rudin's Functional Analysis 1st Chapter while proving a theorem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your map $f$ is just the composition of the map $g:R\to R\times X$ given by $g(\alpha)=(\alpha,x)$ and the scalar multiplication map $h:R\times X\to X$.  By definition of a topological vector space, $h$ is continuous, and $g$ is continuous since it is continuous on each coordinate (on one coordinate it is the identity and on the other it is a constant map).